# mysql how to make difficult selects

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn mysql, but seems like without much success. I do understand how it works and I can do some simple operations with data like insert, update or select. I can do simple selects from one table or select from different tables using joins like in examples that i read so far. I've read a lot of tutorials and articles and i really understand everything but when i face a new exercise i really don't know what to do and how to start with it.

For example let's say that i have following table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE courses (`currency` varchar, `date` date, `course` decimal);

INSERT INTO courses (currency, date, decimal) values ('USD', now(), 5.4);
INSERT INTO courses (currency, date, decimal) values ('EUR', now(), 6.3);
INSERT INTO courses (currency, date, decimal) values ('USD', now(), 5.7);
INSERT INTO courses (currency, date, decimal) values ('EUR', now(), 6.7);
```

And i need to get last courses by each group. I dont even have a clue how to start with that example. At First selected all elements by group:

```
SELECT * FROM courses GROUP BY currency;
```

But I get only first rows from each group. So i googled a little bit and i found out that people use JOIN. But as far as i know JOINS are used when you need to get data from several realated tables, why should i use joins here?

Any advices would be really appreciated.

P.S This is not homework, i really want to understand it

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a first or last row.  If you want to go by insertion order, then include an `auto_increment` column.

Comment: ok what if i need courses by last date

Comment: The JOINs you are referring to are probably joining to a subquery on the same table to find the first ID values (for each grouping), effectively using the JOIN as a result filter.

Comment: @user3673623 Regarding "by last date"; you'll need to be more clear on what you mean by "courses" since all your references to it seem to be grouping on `currency` not `course`. (Also, your `INSERT`s are mistaken in referencing the name of the data type, not the field).

Comment: The data model doesn't really make much sense -- you have a number, a datestamp and a currency type, but no detail about what it is that cost that much at that time.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM courses WHERE currency = 'EUR';` would bring all records with that currency. 
I think the best for you now would be following a tutorial like http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

`group by` is for aggreating different rows, so for instance if you wanted to average the currency `course` across each entry, you might do:

```
select currency,avg(course) from courses group by currency
```

On the other hand, if you wanted the currencies grouped near each other, you would use an `order by` sort:

```
select * from courses order by currency
```

And then if you wanted to further order by insertion time (since you have the insertion time as part of your table) you can also add that to the sort list as a second order sort:

```
select * from courses order by currency, date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a JOIN statement with a subquery that grabs the max (most recent) date.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM courses a
JOIN
(
SELECT
currency, max(date) as maxdate
FROM courses
GROUP BY currency
) b on a.date=b.maxdate and a.currency=b.currency
```

Comment: subqueries are very expensive in MySQL, causing an O(n^2) operation as the subquery is executed once for each row in the main query, and can also cause indexes to be ignored.  Wherever possible, avoid subqueries in MySQL.